# referenced entity not showing up in the node view page or in any view I create

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom module which defines a custom entity. On a content type, I have an 'Entity reference' field that let's me select a custom entity. The value is saved in the database (I looked directly to the database) but is missing when the node is viewed.

if I dump the `$node` in `hook_node_update($node)` I can see the referenced value is there. But on `hook_node_view($nodes, $types)` the value is gone.

The funny part is that in a view, if I create a relation based on this field, I can see the entity's fields, but not the entity reference field value :))

Other types of entities are displayed correctly though, the problem is only with my custom entity

Any help would be very appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: did you look at display setting page?

Comment: yeah, I tried all the options available with no luck.

Comment: if you are using `Entity reference` module, which formatter you set in display setting? `title only` or `rendered entry`

Comment: I tried all of them: label, entity ID and rendered entity. Nothing worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still haven't found an answer so I decided to try the [model](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/model&ei=q1WiT5fBIML_4QSu373GCA&usg=AFQjCNHmqw-9AceHYzacamRTBx7b-IPiRg) module. Looks ok now :)

LATER EDIT: [eck](http://drupal.org/project/eck) module seems the best way to work with entities

Answer (score 2):

I just Googled the same issue and was led to this page.

You need to implement an `access callback` in `hook_entity_info()`, else the entity reference field won't load the entity.